# Is this a good implementation for a Thread Safe Lazily Loaded Singleton in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, lazy-initialization

I want to implement Thread Safe Lazily Loaded Singleton in Java.

Is this a good design?

```
public final class ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton {

private ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton(){}

private static ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton instance;

public static ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton getSynchronizedInstance(){
    synchronized(ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton.class){ 
        if (instance==null){
            instance = new ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

}
```

I also want to create a lock-less version for use in a scenario where one thread accesses the Singleton many more times than the other threads, how would I achieve this using the atomic objects in Java, ie AtomicBoolean or AtomicReference etc. Could you provide a code example please?

Comment: You could also make the entire ```getSynchronizedInstance()``` method ```synchronized```, rather than explicitly getting the lock yourself.

Comment: Of course an `enum` would be much simpler, and faster ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Not to mention that it's the recommended way to implement the Singleton pattern!

Answer (score 3):

A better design would be

```
public final class ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton {

    private ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton(){}

    private static volatile ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton instance;

    public static ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton getSynchronizedInstance(){
        if (instance==null)
            synchronized(ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton.class){ 
                if (instance==null){
                    instance = new ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton();
                }
        return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the best design IMHO is

```
public enum ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: How do enums work under the hood such that they can be used as singletons?

Comment: @aranhakki An `enum` lists all the possible instances by design.  If you specify one INSTANCE, you have a singleton.  It is thread safe and the class is lazy-loaded.

Comment: Why is it that you check if instance is null twice?

Comment: @ericGnuLuver Once the value has been set, you don't want to pay the price of locking every time.

Comment: Right, but why the 2nd null check. By the `synchronized` block, instance is guaranteed to be null -- the following if statement is redundant. EDIT: spelling

Comment: @ericGnuLuver because another thread might have initialized the  singleton while the current thread is acquiring the lock.

Comment: So if the thread acquiring the lock runs into such a situation, it would receive the same instance that the other thread initialized?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach to implementing Singleton design pattern in Java is using the Enum approach. The Enum approach is very simple and thread safe implicitly.

```
public enum EnumTest {
  INSTANCE;

  // Test code
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      // First thread
      Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             EnumTest obj = EnumTest.INSTANCE;
         }   
      });
      t1.start();

      // Second thread
      Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             EnumTest obj = EnumTest.INSTANCE;
         }   
      });  
      t2.start();
   }
 }
```

Nice tutorial [here](https://www.stackstalk.com/2013/11/singleton-pattern-in-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing will probably be as lazy as you need it:

```
private static ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton instance
    = new ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton();

public static ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton instance() {
    return instance;
}
```

True, `instance` will be created as soon as the class is loaded. But the class won't be loaded until it's used, and at that point you probably need to get the instance, anyway.

The only time this wouldn't be as lazy as you need is if the `ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton` class also had static helper methods that don't use `instance`, but that would suggest they don't have much to do with the rest of the class and should probably be moved to their own class.

A lot of people also use a single-value `enum` for singletons. Personally I find it ugly, but it does have some advantages (handles the private constructor and `instance` for you, and the singleton-ness is enforced even if your class is serializable, which is otherwise not trivial).

Comment: I thought the variables within a synchronized block are synchronized for you so changes are published out to shared memory on exit and latest versions are read in on entry, so there is no need for the volatile keyword in my implementation? Also non-final should be fine as it is private? Also shouldn't your implementation need synchronized blocks or a volatile variable?

Comment: @aranhakki Oh, you're right -- what you have isn't a double-checked lock at all. I misread the question. But my implementation doesn't need synchronized/volatile because the `final` modifier also provides happens-before guarantees (somewhat limited ones, but enough for this use).

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know that about the final keyword, upvote me please for spotting your mistake, I could do with the points!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a true lock-free implementation  it would require some spinning.  Otherwise @yshavit or @Peter Lawrey are the best possible answers.

Lock Free:

```
private static final AtomicBoolean created = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private static volatile LazySingleton instance = null;

public static ThreadSafeLazySynchronizedSingleton getIntsance(){
   if(instance != null) return instance.get();

   if(created.compareAndSet(false, true)){
      //only one thread can try and create
      instance = new LazySingleton();
   } else {
      //other thread is creating, spin until ready
      while(instance == null);
   }
   return instance;
}
```

Comment: How can it send out different references? Only one will ever be created and assigned.  I chose not to use AtomicReference because, presumably, it is lazy to prevent creating more than one.  With AtomicReference you can create more than one (ie: 1. create instance 2. try to set that instance in the atomic reference).

Comment: Only one instance can be created, but this _is_ unsafe. Imagine someone comes in right after the CAS but before `created.set(true)`. At that point, `created.get() == true` (due to the CAS), so that second caller returns `instance`. But they did so before that `created.set(true)` provides a HB edge (relative to the `created.get()` they saw), so there's no transitive HB between `return instance` and `instance = new LazySingleton()`. That means that second thread could still see `null` or a partially-constructed object.

Comment: It's still there, in the first line. Btw is `created.get() != null` what you meant? It won't compile (`created.get()` returns `boolean`). I think you need to just get rid of that first line altogether, and just do the CAS-else-spin. (Also the last line needs to be `return instance.get()`, and you could also use one of the local references from the CAS or spin if you wanted.)

Comment: you are correct, i didn't read the first version close enough.